# Adding edges to a graph that satisfy logical expressions

Tags: graphs, colorings

Easy question. I have a homework problem with its answer that i am unable to interpret.

[image]

An explanation on how to arrive at the answer is what I'm looking for.
Please let me know what the palette is too. I'm having a difficult time finding information on this problem.

Comment: Why are the nodes on the left marked with "T", "N" and "F", what do they mean? Is it supposed to use four colors? Why are some edges black and the others blue? Should the graph stay planar?

Comment: This is what I'm asking.

Comment: This type of question seems more appropriate for your course instructor or whoever assigned you this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the graph now. The graph should be colored with three colors, T, F and N, standing for True, False and Neither. The three form a clique (hence the black edges), so that they have to be assigned a different color each. The assigned color should then be interpreted as the respective boolean value assignement. The four literals have an edge to Neither, so that they have to be assgined another value (i.e. True or False). Each literal also has an edge to its negation, so that it has to be assigned another value than its negation. The three nodes on the right can be seen as "helper" nodes. They are needed to ensure that any assignment to A and B will result in A xor B = true.

Comment: @ns533 By the way it seems to me that any coloring will already match A xor B = true, even when removing the three nodes on the right entirely.